# Drop draggable on collapsed div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

My goal is to be able to take a draggable item and drop it on a collapsed div. When the item is dropped it will be appended to a div that is within the collapsed div.

Put simply, dropping on 'outter_collapsed' will place the item in 'inner'

```
<div id = "outter_collapsed">
<div id = "inner">
<!-- DROPPED ITEM PLACED HERE -->
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how you would approach this or possible words of wisdom are welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
$( "#another-div" ).draggable();
        $( "#outter_collapsed" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $(this).children().append(ui.draggable);

            }
        });
```

Check out an example here - http://jsfiddle.net/Bfa9v/19/

Comment: Now what if the item that is being dropped on "outter_collapse" is a sortable item?

Comment: nothing much it will still work. just add $( "#another-div" ).sortable();